# jQuery :odd selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a table with several rows - I assigned a hover function to each row.
what I want to find out in my hover function if the selected TR is odd or even.

I used this code:

```
alert(tr.is(":odd"));
```

unfortunately it doesn't work although it should(?) I'm always getting "false".

I tried getting the rowIndex directly from the TR element like:

```
alert(tr.is(":odd")+"/"+tr.get(0).rowIndex);
```

strange thing: I'm getting the correct rowIndex, but always False from the :odd property.

what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:odd` pseudo selector depends on the element being selected within a context or result set. For instance: `$('ul li:odd')` would select odd elements from that context. I would suggest using this test instead:

```
var odd = (tr[0].rowIndex % 2 == 0);
```

Every other row will return `true` from that expression. Since `rowIndex` is zero-based, we use `value % 2 == 0`. If it were one based, you would use `value % 2 == 1` to get the odd rows.

Answer (score 3):

The `:odd` selector removes even-numbered elements from a set.

When called in `.is()`, the set that it looks at contains only your single `tr` element.  Since it will be at index 0 in that set, it will always be `:even`.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd. :)

But seriously, a single item is always item 0 of that list, which is even.  To have even/odd distinctions, you need to have a list.  What most people do is run some on-load function that adds a class to the odd elements.